# Reading values from DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable populated with samo data/values and I want to read data from DataTable and pass it to a string variable.

I have this code:

```
DataTable dr_art_line_2 = ds.Tables["QuantityInIssueUnit"];
```

I have a countert like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= broj_ds; i++ )
{                                    
    QuantityInIssueUnit_value => VALUE FROM DataTable
    QuantityInIssueUnit_uom  => VALUE FROM DataTable    
}
```

Is this possible or not? If yes then how to pass data from DataTable to those variables?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `broj_ds` (I mean its "origins")?

Comment: It's a int value, serves in a counter, no string to datatable, i use it to count elements in dataset int broj_ds = ds.Tables["Line"].Rows.Count;

Comment: Why would you want to overwrite the value of your variables on each iteration ?

Comment: I have a for-each loop and in it i have this for loop, for loop must execute as many times as for-each does, not more,not less, so i have to build some kind of counter to work all that

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
DataTable dr_art_line_2 = ds.Tables["QuantityInIssueUnit"];

for (int i = 0; i < dr_art_line_2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    QuantityInIssueUnit_value = Convert.ToInt32(dr_art_line_2.Rows[i]["columnname"]);
    //Similarly for QuantityInIssueUnit_uom.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using the foreach loop

```
DataTable dr_art_line_2 = ds.Tables["QuantityInIssueUnit"];

  foreach(DataRow row in dr_art_line_2.Rows)
  {
     QuantityInIssueUnit_value = Convert.ToInt32(row["columnname"]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work

```
for (int i = 1; i <= broj_ds; i++ ) 
  { 

     QuantityInIssueUnit_value = dr_art_line_2[i]["Column"];
     QuantityInIssueUnit_uom  = dr_art_line_2[i]["Column"];

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For VB.Net is

```
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + "database path")
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        da.Fill(dt)

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
            someVar = dt.Rows(i)("fieldName")
        Next
```