# How to merge two columns in one?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to show all books from selected writers from checkedlistbox on chart. Problem is that I need to merge two columns and it throws exception on line da.Fill(dt1): *Invalid column name ime_prezime*

```
            conn.Open();

            //chart1.Series.Clear();
            //string predmeti = "";
            string result = "";
            string[] sAutori;
            foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                DataRowView castedItem = itemChecked as DataRowView;
                string companyName = (string)castedItem["ime_prezime"];
                //int? id = castedItem["autor_id"];
                result += $@"'({companyName})'" + ",";
            }
            
            if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count < 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Morate izabrati bar dva pisca!");
            }
            else
            {
                result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
                //string result = predmeti.Substring(0, predmeti.Length - 1);
                cmd1.CommandText = $@"SELECT a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime AS ime_prezime, COUNT(b.knjiga_id) FROM AUTORI AS a JOIN autori_izdanja AS b ON a.autor_id = b.autor_id WHERE ime_prezime IN ({result}) GROUP BY a.ime";
                da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
                da.Fill(dt1);
                try {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
                    {
                        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row[0], row[1]);
                    }
                    label2.Text = result;
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                }
                catch (Exception g) {

                    MessageBox.Show(g.Message);
                }
                
            }
            conn.Close();
```

Can someone solve this please...

Comment: In your select statement in where condition you need to replace `ime_prezime` to `a.prezime` and then it should work. In where condition you need to use original column name instead of alias of column.

Comment: Now it throws another exception

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: This is query ```$@"SELECT a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime AS ime_prezime, COUNT(b.knjiga_id) FROM AUTORI AS a JOIN autori_izdanja AS b ON a.autor_id = b.autor_id WHERE a.prezime IN ({sAutori}) GROUP BY a.ime"``` and it now throws: >'Incorrect syntax near 'adad'.'

Comment: Does this part need some changes? ```string result = "";
            string sAutori;
            foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                DataRowView castedItem = itemChecked as DataRowView;
                string companyName = (string)castedItem["ime_prezime"];
                //int? id = castedItem["autor_id"];
                result += companyName + ", ";
            }```

Comment: Can I have your discord or something? I really need this one please... I'm in high scool and I need it in 5 hours :D

Comment: This is some error about output like it is separated incorrectly or something like that

Comment: When I select first two for example the sAutori gets value Aleksandar Puskin,Emily Bronte and it says that it have syntax error after Puskin. Also throws error on line da.Fill(dt1);

Comment: There is error for last `,`  from for loop append result string. You can remove last `,` by checking `if (result != string.Empty) {result.RemoveLast(",");} ` after foreach loop

Comment: I did it like this>: ```sAutori = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);``` I also changed line ```result += companyName + ",";```

Comment: You don't need to store that after in sAutori. just use result

Comment: Still the same error as the last one I mentioned 3 comments above. Can I send you a full code somewhere?

Comment: `result += "'"+companyName+"'" + ",";` Add `'`

Comment: Now this is exception without editing query: >Column 'AUTORI.prezime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: I need to show writers on chart which I select in ```checkedListBox```. The problem is that they are ordered by ```ime_prezime``` in ```checkedListBox``` so I can't just use their id in that case

Comment: If you have some other idea how to do it I'm open for that

Comment: In group by instead of `a.ime` use `b.knjiga_id` ,`ime_prezime` add `SELECT a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime AS ime_prezime, COUNT(b.knjiga_id) FROM AUTORI AS a JOIN autori_izdanja AS b ON a.autor_id = b.autor_id WHERE a.prezime IN ({sAutori}) GROUP BY ime_prezime ` . Please see edit one

Comment: Now again in the da.Fill(dt1) therows exception > Invalid column name 'ime_prezime'

Comment: `SELECT a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime AS ime_prezime, COUNT(b.knjiga_id) FROM AUTORI AS a JOIN autori_izdanja AS b ON a.autor_id = b.autor_id WHERE a.prezime IN ({result}) GROUP BY a.ime ,   a.prezime` . Please see edit one

Comment: Now it doesn't have exceptions but it doesn't write anything on chart

Comment: If you can debug, please check dataTable values. I think this example will help you further https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556935/reading-values-from-datatable

Comment: Well variable result returns all writers that i select but It doesn't set any rows in table

Comment: Is there data in your table with those selections ? Debug the code and get sql query and run in SQL

Comment: Also can you please accept my answer that would be appreciated. As your error which was showing in code has been resolved.

Comment: Yes I can of course. Problem is that it throws exception again when you write ```ime_prezime``` after ```where```

Comment: I have added `a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime` in Where. Check with this query. It might give you some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlCommand cmd1;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt;
        DataTable dt1;

        void Connection()
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-QEDL8JA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EvidencijaKnjiga;Integrated Security=True;";
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd1.Connection = conn;
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt1 = new DataTable();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        }

        void stats()
        {
            Connection();
            //string select = "SELECT";
        }
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connection();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT autor_id, ime + ' ' + prezime AS ime_prezime FROM autori ORDER BY ime_prezime";
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            checkedListBox1.DataSource = dt;
            checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "ime_prezime";
            checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "autor_id";
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
            button1.Enabled = true;
            //chart1.Series.Clear();
            //chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
            checkedListBox1.ClearSelected();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connection();
            conn.Open();
            /*cmd.CommandText = "SELECT autor_id, ime + ' ' + prezime AS ime_prezime FROM autori ORDER BY ime_prezime";
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);*/
            //chart1.Series.Clear();
            //string predmeti = "";
            string result = "";
            //string sAutori;
            foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                DataRowView castedItem = itemChecked as DataRowView;
                string companyName = (string)castedItem["ime_prezime"];
                //int? id = castedItem["autor_id"];
                result += "'" + companyName + "'" + ",";
            }

            if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count < 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Morate izabrati bar dva pisca!");
            }
            else
            {
                if (result != string.Empty)
                {
                    result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
                }
                //string result = predmeti.Substring(0, predmeti.Length - 1);
                cmd1.CommandText = $@"SELECT a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime AS ime_prezime, COUNT(b.knjiga_id) FROM AUTORI AS a JOIN autori_izdanja AS b ON a.autor_id = b.autor_id WHERE a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime IN ({result}) GROUP BY a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime";
                da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
                da.Fill(dt1);
                //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
                try
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
                    {
                        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row[0], row[1]);
                    }
                    label2.Text = result;
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                }
                catch (Exception g)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(g.Message);
                }

            }
            conn.Close();
        }```
This is the final code. I just ujusted some things and it worked. Thank you so much on help :D
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
           conn.Open();

            //chart1.Series.Clear();
            //string predmeti = "";
            string result = "";
            string[] sAutori;
            foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                DataRowView castedItem = itemChecked as DataRowView;
                string companyName = (string)castedItem["ime_prezime"];
                //int? id = castedItem["autor_id"];
                result += "'"+companyName+"'" + ",";
            }
            
            if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count < 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Morate izabrati bar dva pisca!");
            }
            else
            {
                if(result != string.Empty ){
                    result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
                }
                //string result = predmeti.Substring(0, predmeti.Length - 1);
                cmd1.CommandText = $@"SELECT a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime AS ime_prezime, COUNT(b.knjiga_id) FROM AUTORI AS a JOIN autori_izdanja AS b ON a.autor_id = b.autor_id WHERE a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime IN ({result}) GROUP BY a.ime  + ' ' + a.prezime";
                da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
                da.Fill(dt1);
                try {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
                    {
                        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row[0], row[1]);
                    }
                    label2.Text = result;
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                }
                catch (Exception g) {

                    MessageBox.Show(g.Message);
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: Just change CommandText to ```$@"SELECT a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime AS ime_prezime, COUNT(b.knjiga_id) FROM AUTORI AS a JOIN autori_izdanja AS b ON a.autor_id = b.autor_id WHERE a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime IN ({result}) GROUP BY a.ime + ' ' + a.prezime"``` and it works perfect